# argument of type "uint8_t" is incompatible with parameter of type "uint8_t *"

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, keil

I am trying to compile a [USB HID example code](http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=cs&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmcu.cz%2Fcomment-n2848.html) on Keil for a STM32F4-Discovery. This code allows me to send and receive message to and from a software called "USB HID Demonstrator".

But I have a problem in the `USBD_HID_DataOut` function. The line:

`USB_OTG_ReadPacket((USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE*)pdev, *Buffer, HID_OUT_PACKET);`

Gives me an error:

> error #167: argument of type "uint8_t" is incompatible with parameter
>   of type "uint8_t *"

When I suppress the `*` of `Buffer`, the code compiles but doesn't seem to work (the buffer values received don't match what is expected but I'm perhaps mistaken about that)
and actually the second argument of `USB_OTG_ReadPacket` must be a pointer so I don't understand why this error occurs.

The `Buffer` variable is defined as follow: `uint8_t Buffer[6];`

So is there a problem with the compiler? Do I have to deal with special issues copying this project code into Keil since it was first created for Atollic?

Or is there simply a mistake in the link?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't make sense to pass `*Buffer`, because that means the same as `Buffer[0]`. Why would you write `*Buffer` instead of `Buffer[0]` in the first place? `Buffer` isn't even declared as a pointer, so why would you dereference it? (You can, but it just doesn't look right.)

If the function expects a pointer, than passing `Buffer` is correct, since it means the same as `&Buffer[0]`.

Try to clarify your question. What is it *you* want to pass to the function? Do you want to pass it the first uint8_t element in the Buffer array? In that case, you want to pass `Buffer[0]` or `*Buffer` (both mean the same thing.) Or do you want to pass a pointer to the array? In that case, pass `Buffer` or `&Buffer[0]` (both are equivalent.)

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the file `usbd_hid_core.c.bak` at the same line, you can see that there, the author is calling the function correctly:

`USB_OTG_ReadPacket((USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE*)pdev, Buffer, HID_OUT_PACKET);`

Since it's declared as an array, you just need to pass the variable name for the reasons Nikos C. mentioned. See [this Daniweb thread post](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/11705/c-language-problm-how-to-pass-pointer-to-a-function#post57647) for more information on passing pointers to functions.

If you are not receiving the expected values, you will need to debug the flow of that information. I suggest adding `Buffer` to a Watch window and stepping through your program to see what the value in your `Buffer` actually is and if it is changing at some unexpected point.